# Is it possible to JSON a .NET dictionary when the key is a non-string object?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to have controller GET action that returns a JSON-serialized dictionary.  The key to the dictionary is a simple class with two primitives as properties - call it ClassOne.  However, I receive the following error when attempting to JSON the dictionary:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[ClassOne],[ClassTwo]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.
```

The phrase "keys must be strings or objects" implies that it IS possible to serialize a dictionary that has objects as its keys.  However, I cannot find a way to do so.  What are my options in this situation?

Comment: What API are you using to "JSON" your data?

Comment: Without specifying which JSON serialization library you are using, this quesiton is incomplete.  Using `DataContractJsonSerializer`, I got it working and didn't experience an exception, though the JSON it produced might have been a bit wacky (can't tell).  Also, can you provide a minimal code sample that repros your problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, no.  A dictionary from .net would serialize to a hash in Javascript.  A hash can only have strings as keys, so you wouldn't be able to serialize a non-string key.  You can simply transform your dictionary into a serializable one like this:

```
myDictionary.ToDictionary(k => k.Key.Prop1 + "|" + k.Key.Prop2, v => v.Value);
```

Perhaps cleaner would be to give `ClassOne` a `ToString` override and just call `k.Key.ToString()` in the code above.

Comment: It looks like we're going with creating a string key out of the object.  Thank you!